# Simple graph with odd circuit can't be 2-colored.

Tags: graph-theory

Show that a simple graph that has a circuit with an od number of vertices in it cannot be coloured using two colours.

Comment: as Gerry Myerson mentioned, please tell what effort have you made in this question.

Comment: Can you color a triangle with 2 colors?

Comment: @Shahab Front in white, back in black!

Comment: @draks: I mean coloring the vertices, of course. In this context the triangle is a circuit with three vertices.

Comment: @Shahab I know, but when there's a chance to bring AC/DC to M.SE, I can resist it...

Answer (score 3):

Use proof by contradiction; suppose that you could color the graph with 2 color and then consider a circuit with an odd number of vertices, what will be happened then?

*P.S* : because of the homework tag I rather not to clarify more.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose it is $2$-colored, then we may write $V(G)=S_1\cap S_2$ where $S_1$ and $S_2$ are stable sets. Let $C=x_1x_2...x_{2k+1}$ be an odd cycle in $G$.

Discuss the position of each $x_i$ in $V(G)=S_1\cap S_2$ to get the contradiction.